# parse error while using botan for enumerated type PRIVATE = 0xC0

Tags: c++, c, botan

I am using Botan-1.4.12 alongwith GNU gcc/g++ 2.95.3 for some legacy code. Will change to newer version of compiler as well newer version of botan later. But, with the legacy code and Botan-1.4.12, I am getting some strange parse error as explained bwlow.
In my codebase, I have used the following include files:

```
#include <botan/botan.h>
#include <botan/look_pk.h>
#include <botan/dsa.h>
```

And, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /opt/botan/include/botan/symkey.h:10,
from /opt/botan/include/botan/base.h:10,
from /opt/botan/include/botan/botan.h:6,
/opt/botan/enums.h:43: parse error before `0x20'
```

The reason is (in /opt/botan/include/botan/enums.h)

```
enum ASN1_Tag {
   EOC              = 0x00,
   BOOLEAN          = 0x01,
   INTEGER          = 0x02,
. . . .
    PRIVATE          = 0xC0, 
. . . 

};
```

If I change PRIVATE = 0xC0 to say ZPRIVATE = 0xC0

the problem gets apparently solved.
Any better remedy?

Comment: Your question mentions `g++` but it is tagged `c`.

Comment: The problem is solved with other letters? I mean CPRIVATE and so on?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I am using g++ compiler but the source code is essentially C code, added C++ tag

Comment: @LPs Yes, the problem gets solved with other letters as well, e,g, CPRIVATE, ZPRIVATE etc

Comment: Try launching `gcc` with `-E` option to see if `PRIVATE` is already defined somewhere else.

Comment: @LPs When I do gcc with _E, for that line, it shows  0x20 = 0xC0 for the line that had PRIVATE - 0xC0, but nowhere I could see PRIVATE already defined somewhere, is it clashing with something else? remedy?

Comment: It seems that PRIVATE is already defined as `0x02` (e.g. `#define PRIVATE 0x20)` Try to put an `#ifdef PRIVATE #undef PRIVATE` before the `enum` or before the include of header.

Comment: @LPs many thanks, #ifdef PRIVATE #undef PRIVATE #endif worked perfectly

Comment: It compiles, but it isn't a solution. If somewhere else the code define `PRIVATE` as `0x20`  some code needs it defined as `0x20`. So you should check where it is defined at that value and check all repercussion of your modification.

Comment: Since, in C enum values are global, you should always prefix them. E.g. `ASN1__EOC`, `ASN1_BOOLEAN`, `ASN1_INTEGER`, etc.

Comment: Which Botan release would be compatible with GNU gcc/g++ 2.95.3 and does not need to make any change like this?

Comment: @Debasish - If you compile your source file with `-E` (use it like `-c`), then GCC will save preprocessed source as a `*.ii` file. E.g., `g++ <other options> -E foo.cpp`. You will uncover the culprit header that is defining `PRIVATE` to something else. It could be a system or GCC header since `PRIVATE` seems fairly germane.